# How to Get email template in dynamically choose format(For example Html Or Text) using Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, email, html

I need to get email template in dynamically choose format(For example Html Or Text) while customer orders anything in Magento 2.

For Example:
           Customer account has one option, which Email template format you want for Html or text.  After Customer order, something in my site then, send email to customer account what format he chose.

How to achieve this solution? send me a suggestion to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**There is two methods to create email template as well magento 1x.**

1. Create your own html and place in email template.
2. Generate email template based on default template.

Also you can write inline css or external style as given in magento.

**you can find email header and footer and css files files form the following path and override in your theme.**

```
magento\vendor\magento\module-email\view\frontend\header.phtml
magento\vendor\magento\module-email\view\frontend\footer.phtml

magento\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\email.less
magento\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\email-inline.less
magento\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\email-fonts.less
```